# How do I select all overlapping features (in the same layer)?

Tags: qgis

I recently moved to QGIS 2.18.3

On my old QGIS when I clicked on a feature with another feature(s) beneath it, in the same layer, it would highlight them all and all beneath my mouse click or box would be selected in the attribute table.

Now on QGIS it only selects the top feature, which restricts how I use QGIS.
Is there a way to select all under a point?
Or at the very least, is the a keyboard button I can press to cycle through the features when I click, like I used to be able to do in mapinfo. - I've tried a few to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also get it by doing a little rectangle on your feature with the selection tool (just keep your mouse push when selecting and draw a rectangle). It will select every feature below your rectangle. 
A simple click will select only the top feature as you notice...

Comment: That's just what I need, thanks you. That must have been what the difference was all along, or perhaps there wasn't the click/box difference previously. - I use to work a lot with polygons and would box select a lot, but have been working with point data recently so haven't been doing that - you'll made my life a whole lot easier now.

Comment: Glad to help! Please accept the answer so this question won't be unanswered anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit that is not a functionality of QGIS that I had every noticed. Mine has only ever selected the top feature.

However, there is a plugin called Multiple Layer Selection which will do this. It adds a new icon to the toolbar and allows you to select 'stacked' features. If you only have one layer switched on it will select all features in that layer under the mouse click.

Comment: A bit clunkier then I had before, as I've got to turn off all polygon layers above it, but does do what I need it to do. - Thanks

Comment: If you're interested in specific layers you could perhaps streamline that by setting up a preset view of specific layers (the eye symbol above the table of contents). Turn on the layers you want and then add a new preset.  Cuts down on the number of mouseclicks a bit perhaps?